# How can i see wi-fi data in my system?

Tags: wifi

If i connect a wifi device in my circuit.I am tx(transmitted) the signals from the wi-fi device.I want to know about,how the signals are Tx in what format and can  i see the data that is tx (monitoring)???

Comment: For that you need to read the data sheet of the device you want to use. Without more information about that we cannot help you further.

Comment: This question currently does not have enough detail for us to understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

As Joel B pointed out, Wi-Fi traffic can be sniffed using software and remote PC. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html) is your friend. Please note, however, sniffing card should 
support [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).

Traffic can be sniffed locally as well. If your device is running embedded Linux, you can create a monitor interface and use [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump). Be aware, that sniffing Wi-Fi traffic using tcpdump will not give you all packets, because some control packets will be filtered out by firmware (but most likely you don't want them anyways, unless you are Wi-Fi driver developer). Also, monitor mode is not supported by all drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view over the air WiFi traffic (this is known as "sniffing"), the (somewhat) standard way of doing this is using a computer with a [wireless adapter](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/wireshark_enhancements/airpcap.php) and [monitoring software](http://www.winpcap.org/).  The software should let you start capturing all traffic or filter out only certain traffic of interest to you.  Then you can decompose packets in the software and see the various components of each packet.